# How to Convert Web Form Values for Stored Procedure Parameters Using TableAdapters

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, parameters, tableadapter

I am creating a Web Form using TableAdapters with stored procedures and I am having a very difficult time finding a reference for the proper way to convert values from form fields for stored procedure parameters. I have strings, dates, and integers. I think the strings and dates are formatted correctly, but I am unsure about the integers.

I keep getting an "Input string was not in a correct format." error when I run the application. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Here is the TableAdapter Wizard-generated test stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].InsertQuery
(
@firmName nvarchar(100),
@address nvarchar(200),
@city nvarchar(50),
@state nvarchar(2),
@zipcode nvarchar(15),
@phoneNumber nvarchar(MAX),
@emailAddress nvarchar(MAX),
@website nvarchar(MAX),
@desiredEffDate datetime,
@desiredLimits nvarchar(50),
@desiredLimitsOther1 nvarchar(100),
@desiredLimitsOther2 nvarchar(100),
@desiredDeductible nvarchar(20),
@retroDate datetime,
@insurance nvarchar(10),
@currentCarrier nvarchar(100),
@currentPremium nvarchar(50),
@firmEstablished datetime,
@numParalegals int,
@numStaff int,
@engageLetters nvarchar(10),
@conflictSystem nvarchar(10),
@docketSystem nvarchar(10),
@sueFees nvarchar(10),
@numAttorneys int,
@numClaims int,
@complaint nvarchar(10),
@refusedAdmission nvarchar(10),
@signature nvarchar(200)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Firms] ([firmName], [address], [city], [state], [zipcode], [phoneNumber], [emailAddress], [website], [desiredEffDate], [desiredLimits], [desiredLimitsOther1], [desiredLimitsOther2], [desiredDeductible], [retroDate], [insurance], [currentCarrier], [currentPremium], [firmEstablished], [numParalegals], [numStaff], [engageLetters], [conflictSystem], [docketSystem], [sueFees], [numAttorneys], [numClaims], [complaint], [refusedAdmission], [signature]) VALUES (@firmName, @address, @city, @state, @zipcode, @phoneNumber, @emailAddress, @website, @desiredEffDate, @desiredLimits, @desiredLimitsOther1, @desiredLimitsOther2, @desiredDeductible, @retroDate, @insurance, @currentCarrier, @currentPremium, @firmEstablished, @numParalegals, @numStaff, @engageLetters, @conflictSystem, @docketSystem, @sueFees, @numAttorneys, @numClaims, @complaint, @refusedAdmission, @signature)
```

Here is the code behind:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirmsTableAdapter InsertFirmAdapter = new FirmsTableAdapter();
        InsertFirmAdapter.InsertQuery(
            txtFirmName.Text, 
            txtAddress1.Text, 
            txtCity.Text, 
            ddStates.SelectedValue, 
            txtZip.Text, 
            txtPhone.Text, 
            txtEmail.Text, 
            txtWebsite.Text, 
            Convert.ToDateTime(txtEffDate.Text), 
            ddLimits.SelectedValue, 
            txtLimits1.Text, 
            txtLimits2.Text, 
            ddDeductible.SelectedValue, 
            Convert.ToDateTime(txtRetroDate.Text), 
            cblInsurance.Text, 
            txtCurrCarrier.Text, 
            txtCurrPrem.Text, 
            Convert.ToDateTime(txtEstDate.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNumParalegals.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtNumClerical.Text), 
            cblEngageLetters.Text,
            cblConflictSystem.Text, 
            cblDocketSystem.Text, 
            cblSueFees.Text, 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalAttys.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtClaimsQuantity.Text), 
            cblComplaint.Text, 
            cblRefusedAdmission.Text, 
            txtSignature.Text);
    }
```

Before I switched to using TableAdapters I was using SQL commands and this code worked, so I'm surprised the TableAdapter calls are not:

```
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EstimateDB"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertQuery", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firmName", txtFirmName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtCity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", ddStates.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zipcode", txtZip.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneNumber", txtPhone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@website", txtWebsite.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@desiredEffDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtEffDate.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desiredLimits", ddLimits.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desiredLimitsOther1", txtLimits1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desiredLimitsOther2", txtLimits2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desiredDeductible", ddDeductible.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@retroDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtRetroDate.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insurance", cblInsurance.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentCarrier", txtCurrCarrier.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentPremium", txtCurrPrem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@firmEstablished", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtEstDate.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numParalegals", txtNumParalegals.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numStaff", txtNumClerical.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@engageLetters", cblEngageLetters.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conflictSystem", cblConflictSystem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docketSystem", cblDocketSystem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sueFees", cblSueFees.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numAttorneys", txtTotalAttys.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numClaims", txtClaimsQuantity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@complaint", cblComplaint.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refusedAdmission", cblRefusedAdmission.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@signature", txtSignature.Text);

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about formatting strings before passing them to `InsertFirmAdapter.InsertQuery`. You actually need proper objects, as some of the params in stored procedure are declared as integers and datetime. So the error is thrown by one of the `Convert.To` calls. You can trace it by logging or debugging. What are the actual values before the call?

**EDIT**
You can write own methods to verify user input. Normally you would do that at a higher level than right be fore executing query, to be able to notify user about invalid data provided. This an example for converting `string` to `int`, you can infer `string` to `DateTime` conversion from it.

```
int ParseInt32WithDefault(string value, int defaultValue) {
    int number;
    if (Int32.TryParse(value, out number))
        return number;
    return defaultValue;
}
```

And call it instead of `Convert.ToInt32` ex.: `ParseInt32WithDefault(txtNumParalegals.Text, 0)`.
However, this doesn't solve the problem but rather masks it. You need to see a list of values of all variables that you do `Convert.To...`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm pretty sure you're right, it is one of the `Convert.ToInt32` calls. If I just insert the basic `txtNumParalegals.Text` for any of those calls then IntelliSense indicates "cannot convert from 'string' to 'int?'". When I add `Convert.ToInt32` to these calls IntelliSense is satisfied. The values for these calls come from controls like: `<asp:TextBox id="txtNumParalegals" runat="server" maxlength="3" style="width: 30px;"></asp:TextBox>`. How else can I format these calls to make the values compliant?

Comment: IntelliSense notifies you about object conversion. You need to explicitly convert string into integer. However at run time you also need proper data to be passed to `Convert.ToInt32`. I.e. empty string or alpha symbols will fail to be parsed. See update for a possible solution

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation! I understand what you're saying, but I'm surprised because before I switched to using TableAdapters I had the insert working with standard SQL command calls like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numParalegals", txtNumParalegals.Text);`, which seems pretty straight forward. Why the added complexity and resulting problem with TableAdapters?

Comment: I added the full SQL command code above in case you can gather more information about the issue with the TableAdapter calls. Thanks again!

Comment: The above method does allow the insert to succeed, and I applied it only to the `Convert.ToInt32` calls, so those were the culprits. The `Convert.ToDateTime` method works. I still wonder, what is the recommended standard method for converting a string value to an integer. Thanks!

Comment: It's the ABC of interactive (with user) applications. Any input that can come from a human should be validated. Good manners are to notify user about some fields failing validation and why. So this code should be placed in View or Controller, using `TryParse` directly. And method performing query to DB should get _clean_ values, which shouldn't be verified

Comment: I located the the source of the problem, but I don't know yet why it is a problem. `Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalAttys.Text)` was being passed a null value during testing, which shouldn't be a problem because `txtTotalAttys` is not a required field and is specified in the database as a field that can accept null. I will continue to investigate.